# Is it possible to use Google Sign-In from an SDK inside of an App/Game?

Tags: ios, google-signin

I am building an SDK that developers will have inside of their games/apps. I am trying to find out how to get Google Sign-in to work. It is trying to use the bundle id of the game itself instead of the bundle id of my sdk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else inquiring. We got this to work by first adding in the url schemes via google into our sdk and then adding the url scheme of sdk bundle id to the game/app, which we did via a compile script